# Angular mat-autocomplete not showing options

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I am using an auto-complete so users can select an address (or search for it and select it).

On the same page, users can add addresses. After they add the address, I want to add the address to the mat-autocomplete.

My issue is currently that the mat-autocomplete isn't showing any options. For troubleshooting I setup a div which uses *ngFor to show the addresses and that works and updates.

// component (left out some code)

```
filteredAddresses_pickup;

constructor(public translate: TranslateService, private addressService: 
AddressService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.addresses = this.route.snapshot.data['addresses'];

this.filteredAddresses_pickup = Observable.create((observer: Observer<Address[]>) => {
  observer.next(this.addresses);

  this.addressService.addressesChanged.subscribe(
    (addresses: Address[]) => {
      observer.next(addresses);
      this.addresses = addresses;
      console.log(this.addresses);
    });

  this.pickupaddress.valueChanges.subscribe(value_entered => {
    console.log(value_entered);
    console.log(this._filterAddresses(value_entered));
    observer.next(this._filterAddresses(value_entered));
  });


});
}
```

component HTML:

```
              <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="{{ 'mainapp.shipment.pickupaddress' | translate }}"
                       attr.aria-label="{{ 'mainapp.shipment.pickupaddress' | translate }}" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                       [formControl]="pickupaddress"
                >
                <ng-template *ngIf="filteredAddresses_pickup | async; else loadingtwee">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption [displayWith]="displayAddress"><!---->
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let pickup of filteredAddresses_pickup | async" [value]="pickup">
                    <span>{{pickup.name}}, {{pickup.postalcode}}, {{pickup.country}}</span>
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
                </ng-template>
              </mat-form-field>
<div *ngIf="filteredAddresses_pickup | async; else loading">
  <div *ngFor="let a of filteredAddresses_pickup | async">
    <span>{{a.name}}, {{a.postalcode}}, {{a.country}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  Textdiv...
</ng-template>
<ng-template #loadingtwee>
  Dropdown...
</ng-template>
```

I don't see mat-options (it only works as an input text field) but I do see multiple spans who filter when I enter something in the input field or when addressChanged gets triggered.

How to fix this?

Comment: please add stackblitz example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by removing the second mat-autocomplete that was on the right side. I hadn't properly configured the second one yet and it seemed to interfere with the first one (without giving errors).

If you have the same problem:
Remove all other mat-autocomplete, check if your (broken) mat-autocomplete works and slowly re-add the others.

Comment: Oh, god. I have been trying to debug this since this morning. Lifesaver :)

Comment: I need to use both of them

Answer (score 7):

Add this in style.scss. It should fix the issue.

`.cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-overlay-pane { z-index: 9999 !important; }`

Comment: Thanks @Arun Kumar It saved my day

Comment: @Roster I am glad that it helped.

Comment: In my case I had to add position: relative because position was fixed and z-index doesn't work with that